# Скажите как перекрасить у SeekBar backgroind?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно перекрасить. Не изменять Drawable. А именно перекрасить белый цвет на красный.

Левая часть вместе с кнопкой легко краситься. А вот Правая часть или точнее быть, задняя часть вообще ни как не краситься....Подскажите

Если можно то через XML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создайте `xml` файл в папке `drawable`, например `progress_bar.xml` и пропишите в нем:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Первый `solid` это цвет как вы сказали задней части, а второй `solid` это цвет прогресс строки. Можете указать нужный цвет, а если хотите чтобы было по стандарту то укажите цвет `colorAccent`.
Далее в вашем `activity`:

```
SeekBar mSeekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
mSeekBar.setProgressDrawable(getResources()
.getDrawable(R.drawable.progress_bar));
```

По стандарту строка будет толстой, можете задать нужный размер:

```
<SeekBar
 android:id="@+id/seekBar"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:minHeight="3dp"
 android:maxHeight="3dp"
 android:layout_margin="16dp"/>
```

И готово.

Answer (score 0):

Или создай bg.9.png и добавь android:progressDrawable="bg"