# Почему на разных версиях android progressBar выглядит по разному?

Tags: android

Здравствуйте. Использую горизонтальный progressBar для отображения % соотношения одной из характеристик.(Т.е имеется например 5 горизонтальных progressBar, у которых progress в сумме равен 100%, например 25,50, 10,10,5). У каждого progressBar задан свой цвет полосы progressTint. Кроме того я указал progressBackgroundTintMode, чтобы не занятая часть полосы progress была такого же цвета как и фон экрана. Проблема заключается в том что на различных версиях android progressBar выглядит по разному, где то progressTint не срабатывает, где то progressBackgroundTintMode становится черного цвета.

Сам progressBar я пытался задать через `android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar` и `ProgressBar` , в первом случае хотя бы progressTint отображается нужный, но вот progressBackgroundTintMode все равно отображается черного цвета...
Подскажите как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Попробуйте поставить прогрес бару стиль из суппорт библиотеки  `style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"`.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать кастомные цвета которые буду применены на любом `api`, думаю [этот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/665171/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83-seekbar-backgroind/665243#665243)
ответ будет полезен в качестве примера как это сделать.